# Can I clear a NSDatePicker?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can I clear a NSDatePicker ?

I would like to not see any day selected.

thanks

Comment: No you need to add a date, you can't have it show an empty field if you plan on using the standard `NSDatePicker`. You might be able to do it by subclassing.

Comment: @dragon112 and then? Should I override drawInRect ? How does it work exactly ?

Comment: what is the point to clear the `NSDatePicker`?

Comment: @holex I want all days unselected

Comment: @Patrick, I undertand it, but what do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @holex What do you mean? I need to provide visual feedback about an user action, by unselecting all days

Comment: @Patrick, what is wrong with a extra button beside (above, below etc...) the `NSDatePicker` with name _Remove Date_ or _Reset Date_ or something... and when the user taps that button, you can remove the previously selected date from your database.

Comment: @holex: The questioner's app still needs to reflect that fact in the UI, hence the question: How to clear the date picker to reflect that there is no longer a date set.

Comment: Here's something that won't work: Setting the date picker's `objectValue` or `dateValue` to `nil`. (I just checked.)

Comment: @PeterHosey, I had knew it, this is why I asked the purpose of it. the developer should have known it, and he can inform his customer of how the `UI` works in iOS. there are some things what are not possible...

Comment: @holex: This question isn't about iOS.

Comment: @PeterHosey, it makes someone else headache... :( because he has to develop a `CustomDatePicker`, which has this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no!

But you can for example subclass it and replace drawInRect method...

Comment: Thanks how exactly ? Could you give me some more information ?

Comment: - (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // do nothing
}

Comment: This method, drawTextInRect, is a NSTextField method and not available for NSDatePicker. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: No, sorry, you are right ... Another idea: you create an empty NSText control and set it in front of NSDatePicker :) BTW, what is a point of cleat it?

Comment: I want all days unselected

Answer (score 0):

The following NSDatePicker subclass can show an empty date state and represents a nil binding as such.

https://github.com/ThesaurusSoftware/TFDatePicker

Run the TFDatePickerTest to see how it behaves.